# Why doesn't rule 1 consequence effect behavior of rule 2?

Tags: drools

As an exercise in teaching myself drools I'm working on rules for bidding in the bridge card game.  The rules work independently of each other (enforced by use of drools.halt() in the rules) but when I try to extend the example by removing the halt() calls, I get behavior I didn't expect.  In the example below I am commenting out the halt() in the first rule, and adding the size() condition to the 2nd rule to replace it, trying to prevent the 2nd rule from  firing.  I would not expect the 2nd rule to fire because the consequence of the first rule added a bid to the Auction's collection, and so subsequently in rule 2 the count should not be zero.  I've tried explicitly adding the 'update' or 'modify' directives in the first rule, but that didn't make any difference.

```
rule "rule1"
salience 100
    when
        $auction : Auction( $currentBidder : currentBidder != null )
        $hand : Hand( owner.equals($currentBidder), getTotalPoints(getLongestSuit()) >= 13 )
    then
        $auction.bid($currentBidder, new Bid(1, $hand.getLongestSuit()));
        //drools.halt();
end

rule "rule2"
salience 1
    when
        $auction : Auction( $currentBidder : currentBidder != null, getPlayerBids().size() == 0 )
        Hand(owner.equals($currentBidder))
    then
        $auction.bid($currentBidder, new Pass());
        drools.halt();
end
```

Answer (score 0):

When you change an object, you need to tell the engine you updated it.  So try adding update($action); at the end of the first rule.